# Package windows phone app with visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

In visual studio 2013, when I Finished my First Windows Phone App and ready to Package it to Upload But I cannot find Store Option in Project Menu..

But When I make a windows store Application the Store option Appear. Can someone suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this link might be useful:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454036.aspx

The link explains - Packaging your Store app by using Visual Studio:

1. Configure an app package - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230259.aspx
2. Create an app package - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975357.aspx

To access the Store by using commands in Visual Studio:

> You can interact with the Store by using the Store menu in Visual
>   Studio. In Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, open the Project menu, and
>   then choose Store. The Store menu appears only if you’re working on a
>   Store project or solution. In Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows,
>   the Store menu appears directly on the menu bar. The first three
>   commands on the menu are always available, but the availability of the
>   other commands depends upon where you are in the development process.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a Windows Phone Silverlight app, not a Windows Phone Runtime app. The separate step to build appx packages is only for the latter. Silverlight apps always generate their xap file when building. Look for it in the project's bin\Release directory.

See my blog entry [Why can’t I create an app package? Windows Phone Xap vs. Appx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/08/07/why-can-t-i-create-an-app-package-windows-phone-xap-vs-appx.aspx) for more detail.